# call 7zip extract here function

Tags: batch-file, autohotkey, 7zip

I wanted to use the "Extract here" function of 7zip context menu. For that I've tried several things for now. First I've acted in the context menu via Autohotkey and key Strokes but this fails too often sadly. After that I've tried it now with a batch script. But this batch script, does always execute it in the AHK directory instead of the one that the marked .zip is in.

What it should do:

Basically just go from Context menu --> 7zip Menu and click/call "Extract here". As many left their teeth already on an AHK script (that doesn't do the function) I thought there's maybe a way for this too work in a batch?

Easiest way to reach the function
--> If there was a way to call a context menu function directly via the registry name for example as the .zip´s i want to extract sometimes contain several zip´s or just folder and data.

Current Batch code:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e *.zip
```

Call of the batch via AHK:

```
Run, "C:\Users\ThisPC\Desktop\test batch\batch.bat"
```

First try to fully do it in AHK:

```
    XButton2::
Send, {AppsKey}
Sleep 75
Send, {Down}
Sleep 75
Send, ee
Sleep 75
Send, {Enter}
pageloaded := false
while(pageloaded = false)
{
    sleep 75
    ImageSearch, X, Y, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, Auto Rename.png
    if ErrorLevel = 0
    {
        pageloaded := true
    }
}
Send, {Right}{Right}{Enter}
try 
    {
    Run, "C:\Users\ThisPC\Desktop\Foldery\ProgramData\"
    }
catch e 
    {
    Run, "C:\Users\ThisPC\Desktop\Foldery\"
    }
return
```

EDIT:
With the first solution given it worked like this:
[I selected the 1st.zip:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GtZX.png)

then used the XButton2 while it is selected which extracts the archive["1st.zip":](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6Ab8.png)

There shouldn't be a folder here, rather the things inside with directory sensitivity (like keeping the directorys insideand just place them one "above", in the current directory of the 1st.zip

[Sometimes, the 1st.zip consists of several .zips as they are only allowed to be 20 MB each, so all needs to be extracted:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lrAM.png)
In this case the 1st.zip contains next1.zip ; next2.zip ; next3.zip --> all of those should be 1:1 like they are in the 1st.zip extracted 1:1 in the same folder of the 1st.zip.[like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA5XO.png)

Overall the directory looks like this:

```
1st.zip
|_ another1.zip
|_ another2.zip
|_ another3.zip
```

the "1st.zip" is always named like: DATE_TIME_ALL.zip so that might be helpfull to know

i hope that explained it good, let me know if you have questions :)